# Libgdx Background getting slightly pixelated

Tags: libgdx

Okay so I have a image and it the same size as the width and height I have set up for the camera, but it look slightly pixelated. I don't readjust the size or anything but edges on everything look slightly off. This is just for a menu so I'm just using a Texture and using

```
sb.draw(image, 0, 0)
```

anyone have any ideas?

Comment: A picture is worth a thousand words.

Comment: if your background is texture type then this  should work
bgImage.setFilter(TextureFilter.Linear, TextureFilter.Linear);

Comment: @KumarSaurabh is right, you have to controll your `TextureFilter`. Helpfull article: http://www.badlogicgames.com/wordpress/?p=1403

Comment: but yeah if your bg is coming from a texture packer image then change filters in the packer file generated by default they are nearest set it to linear

Comment: Thanks for the help this worked